# How to fix 'TypeError: Network Request Failed' error after having checked all kinds of solutions?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I've set up a node.js server with app.post and app.get and I want to post the data from the values of my form which the user fills in to insert in the database, in phpmyadmin. I use Express, body-parser, mysql for my node server. Now I use the fetch in my Registration class where I believe that the error comes from. The error is this: TypeError: Network request failed.

I use Android mobile which is connected to my pc through cable. What i've checked/tried:

1. Fetch url is http (not https)
2. I use my ip4 address (ipconfig > Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi > IPv4 address).(not localhost)
3. I've tested the url in Postman. This works, with Postman I can POST and GET the data with the same URL. Only difference is in Postman I use localhost instead of my IPv4 address (ipconfig > Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi > IPv4 address).
4. I've added header Content-Type: application/json. (see fetch code)
5. Added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> to my AndroidManifest.xml (Accepts clear traffic, such as HTTP)
6. I've made this project in RN version 0.60.4 and also 0.59.8, came to same error, only the project I reproduced in 0.59.8, this fetch seems to work fluently with Postman, which it didn't with my project in 0.60.4.
7. Logging the server (only it doesn't show anything, because it goes to the catch error in the fetch) 0.60.4 version can be found on my git here: https://github.com/CPhilipse/httprequest. Same with the 0.59.8 version: https://github.com/CPhilipse/testhttprequest.
8. Using the fetch example from React Native Networking (docs), but then with my url. Gives same error. When I use the url from the example, it works. Which is the reason I believe that the cause is of my url, only I don't see what.

```
async handleRegistration(){
        console.log(this.state.name, this.state.email, this.state.password);
        await fetch('http://my_ip:3000/newCustomer', {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                "name": this.state.name,
                "email": this.state.email,
                "password": this.state.password
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson => console.log(responseJson))
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }
```

This is my fetch code. The uri newCustomer have I defined in Routes.js (node server) Same with the port 3000.

I expect for the fetch to just work and that the data to post. To the very least, not give this error. What I get is this error message which I've been struggling with for days now: TypeError: Network Request Failed. Am I missing something?

Comment: `I use my ip4 address` can you explain that? are you using 127.0.0.1? or your machines internal ip? The problem lies there. I am pretty sure

Comment: @Aritra Chakrabory, I do ipconfig in my terminal and than under Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi you see IPv4 address. That is the one I use. I also think the problem is there, because it doesn't seem to be anywhere else, but what is wrong with it? That's what I don't get.

Comment: is the mobile and your server(in this case your machine) in same network? Otherwise you have to port-forward. Basically you need your mobile and machine connecting to same router.

Comment: @Aritra Chakraborty you are the best. I have my laptop connected to ethernet, it came to my mind before, so I plugged it out but it still didn't work. This comment made me just realize why, I had my laptop on another wifi than my mobile phone. Now I've put them both on the same wifi and instantly it works. It explains so much, thank you so much, this made me fix this issue. How can I make this comment a correct anwser?

Comment: let me put it as an answer, you can select it there for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network Error points to your second point, `I use my ip4 address (not localhost)`.

As you are using your mobile device, and using the **internal ip** (from `ipconfig`) of the server, the Mobile and Server ***needs to be on the same network***. So that the mobile can access the server IP address, to put it simply both needs to be connected to the same router.

But if you are not in the same network, you may need to port forward the server ip:port and access the server from your mobile device using the Public IP(google What is my IP), not the internal private IP.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either async/await or promise chaining, but not both at the same time. Try something like this:

```
try {
    const response = await fetch('http://my_ip:3000/newCustomer', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            "name": this.state.name,
            "email": this.state.email,
            "password": this.state.password
        })
    );

    const data = await response.json();
} catch (e) {
    console.warn(error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I implemented your code, but I still get the same error TypeError: Network Request Failed. Also your code has a syntax error, the fetch isn't being closed.

Comment: @ClemensPhilipse good catch, fixed. Also, it looks like the request never hits the server. Do you have any special policy on your device in regards to http/https? Can you try some different https/http-only URLs?

Comment: Pashtukhov the request doesn't hit the server indeed, otherwise it would've logged the request in my terminal, which it doesn't. That I am aware of my device does not have any special policy in regards to http/https. The example from Networking React Native works on my mobile (can be seen in github project 0.59.8) which is https (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json). I don't know any other http/https api's which I can try, but the fact that the example link works, should say enough to say that there is something with my link, does it not?

Comment: You could try the same URL with http: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json
Not sure about Android, but iOS, for instance, does not allow non-https calls by default (if I remember correctly)

Comment: thanks for your time, the person in the comment above made me realize the issue and solve it, stupid mistake of me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related with the server certificates.

I was running a node.js https server, it was being accessed from web browser and through postman via POST method. But fetch method on react native android app was giving **TypeError: Network request failed** which is very poorly informed.

After so much work, i found the mistake on my certificates. I was using let's encrypt certificate and generated using *win-acme* tool. It generates for .pem files for servers such as node.js. I was using key.pem (make settings.json>PrivateKeyExportable:true) and crt.pem which caused error and I changed the crt.pem with chain.pem file. and then *işte bu** it worked.

** a turkish expression means that's it.

Here is the code for node.js server:

```
const https = require("https"),
  fs = require("fs");

const options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('siteadresi.com-key.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('siteadresi.com-chain.pem', 'utf8') //must be chain.pem
};
const express = require('express')
const qs=require('qs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080); // allow 8080 port on firewall
```